# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing a NULL id to a callback from Obj-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to debug a problem I'm encountering in a 3rd party library and have reached a brick wall. The issue is that I am calling the library in Swift, and passing it a callback. The library then executes Obj-C code which ends up calling the callback with `NULL`, which inexplicably crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

Swift code:

```
return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(app, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: opts) { (res: Any?, err: Error?) in
    guard err == nil else {
        Log.e("Error registering with AWS: \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    Log.i("No error registering with AWS")
}
```

Obj-C code (simplified):

```
- (BOOL)interceptApplication:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(nullable NSDictionary *)launchOptions
resumeSessionWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NULL, NULL);      // Crashes here if 1st argument is NULL
    completionHandler(@"hello", NULL);  // Doesn't crash
    return YES;
}
```

As you can see, I have properly marked the Swift callback to have type `Any?`, so it should accept `NULL/nil` no problem.

If anyone can explain why this is happening and how to fix it that would be fantastic.

Comment: Try adding `nullable` to the `result` and `error` parameters in the Objective-C code.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. `nullable`, `_Nullable` and `__Nullable` are compiler directives, they don't actually affect the code at all during runtime, they only prevent compile-time mistakes.

Comment: How is `res` used in the callback?  That's where the problem is likely to be.  I haven't been able to reproduce the issue in a simplified code example.  You may want to come up with a complete short code sample that others can play with.

Comment: @AnatoliP as the code shows, it’s not. The crash happens when trying to call the callback, not inside it.

Comment: Is Objective-C code in a separately built static library or framework?  Was it built with an older version of Xcode?  Just thinking out loud... Still couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AnatoliP it was in a pod-installed dependency, so it was compiled directly alongside my (swift 4) code. In addition, I tweaked the obj-c code for debugging and the changes compiled, and the bug stayed. So it’s not an old compiler issue.